# Attach row ID to GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, gridview

QUESTION: How can I attach a unique identifier (GUID) to these rows? The GUID is provided a by the SQL query?

I have a GridView populated by a SQL Stored Procedure that queries 4 tables and a checkbox in every row (from an Item Template). All of the resources I found show how to link a datatable to a gridview but I do not see a way to attach an identifier to a datatable row either.

This would all be done on page_load or when requested by the user via button click so I don't think using databound events will help me much.

P.S. This is for implementing a UI where the user can select the data to be requested from a 3rd party API so I do not want to display the GUIDs.

ASP.NET

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White"/>
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSurvey" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="cbSurvey_CheckedChanged"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>  
        <%--1 column here--%>                
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Client" HeaderText="Client" ReadOnly="True"/>
        <%--2 columns here--%>                  
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False"/>
    </Columns>
    <%--styling stuff--%>
</asp:GridView>
```

C#

```
private void DataBind(GridView grid, List<Data> rows)
{
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[5]
{
    //...
    new DataColumn("Client", typeof(string)),
    //...
    new DataColumn("ID", typeof(string))
});

foreach (Data row in rows)
{
    //
    //sql queries
    //get list of string ids
    //

    foreach (string survey in surveys)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();   
        //...       
        dr["Client"] = row.ClientName;          
        //... 
        dr["ID"] = survey;
        //...
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
}

grid.DataSource = dt;
grid.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Look into `DataKeyNames`

Comment: @VDWWD Thank you! After I changed how the gridview was binding data this worked perfectly!